# Is it possible to implement an extension of MS Teams to integrate Files with custom document flow

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have a task to integrate MS Teams with custom document flow.
The document flow provides REST Api to upload document and get metadata values that must be put to document before upload.

What is desired:
Add new menu item to Files tab - "Save To XXX System"
After click on "Save To XXX System" it suppose to display wizard to setup document metadata.
On finish step it will upload document by rest.

I cannot find how to modify Files tab functionality.

Also as an option I'm considering to create new Teams Tab App that will display duplicate of Files Tabs with desired function. But in this case I'm looking for solution how to read list of files from Files tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to modify the Files tab, but your idea of creating a tab should work.

What you need to do is use the MS Graph API to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/sites/root/weburl` where `{groupId}` can be retrieved by calling the `microsoftTeams.getContext()` function (as described in more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context)):

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context) { 
  /* 
  Your function logic here. 
  context.groupId will contain the groupId required for the URL above.
  */ 
});
```

You may also find it more convenient to implement your tab using SharePoint itself instead of writing it from scratch. There are details for how to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab).